# Even with KnowledgeUser I get: Be sure the action is valid for the current state of the article, and that you have permission to perform it, exception

Tags: unit-test, batch, code-coverage, knowledge

I have the below test class:

```
@isTest
public static void batchManagementDraftTest() {
        User u = TestDataFactory.createUserWithRoleLeader();
        User u2 = TestDataFactory.createAnotherUserWithRoleLeader();

        List<Knowledge__kav> queriedKAV;
        List<Knowledge__kav> kavList;

        System.runAs(u) {
            List<Employee__c> listEmployee = TestDataFactory.listEmployeeSingle();
            kavList = TestDataFactory.createKnowledgeInternalFAQ();

            queriedKAV = [
                    SELECT KnowledgeArticleId, createdBy.UserRole.DeveloperName, LastModifiedBy.UserRole.DeveloperName, RecordType.DeveloperName
                    FROM Knowledge__kav
                    WHERE id =: kavList[0].id AND LastModifiedBy.UserRole.DeveloperName != 'Super_User'
                    AND ((LastModifiedBy.UserRole.DeveloperName= 'Leader' AND RecordType.DeveloperName != 'CC')
                    OR LastModifiedBy.UserRole.DeveloperName != 'Leader')
            ];
        }

        System.runAs(u2) {
            update queriedKAV;
        }

        Test.startTest();
        BatchManagement bm = new BatchManagement();
        Database.executeBatch(bam);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Inside the BatchManagement class, there is `KbManagement.PublishingService.deleteDraftArticle(kav.KnowledgeArticleId);`. Unfortunately, when this line is executed I am getting `You can't perform this action. Be sure the action is valid for the current state of the article, and that you have permission to perform it.` Which is strange because I am running as Admin and I have the `UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser` set to `true`.

I tried moving the below part

```
Test.startTest();
BatchManagement bm = new BatchManagement();
Database.executeBatch(bam);
Test.stopTest();
```

to inside of the `System.runAs(u2)` like this:

```
System.runAs(u2) {
    update queriedKAV;
    Test.startTest();
    BatchManagement bm = new BatchManagement();
    Database.executeBatch(bam);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Still it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It might help to have just specifics on what the TestDataFactory does (does it create a draft?) and the parts before the `deleteDraftArticle` in the batch class.  I'm guessing, but it's possible the error is because you're attempting to delete a draft but the article is not in a draft state?

Comment: `TestDataFactory` simply creates a knowledge_kav in draft. As for the code before `deleteDraftArticle`  there are just some bunch of `if else` statements that are used to populate some lists, but no modifications to the `knowledge_kav`  untill you reach the `deleteDraftArticle` line.

Comment: what is the purpose of the update statement after the query? Or did you just copy and paste relevant parts? I don't believe this is a permissions issue - that error message can display for other valid reasons: trying to create a draft of an article when one exits, draft article is in an approval process, using the wrong Id in the knowledge method, etc.

Comment: The thing I found was if I remove the users and directly call the `TestDataFactory.createKnowledgeInternalFAQ()` followed the `executeBatch` between the `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` it works fine. But unforutnately, the query in Batch Start has conditions that required that a `knowlegde` be created by users with particular profile and `lastmodifedBy` by users with a particular value in a custom field etc. that forced me to use the `system.runAs` with various users

Comment: what is the purpose of the update statement after the query? -> I don't update/delete all the records in the start query, only certain ones, that's why the use of `if elses`.